# Routing issue in MVC3 application on IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created MVC3 application with razor and using jquery (beginner level) and it's working fine. 
After that i have hosted this application on IIS (created **MVCDemo** Virtual directory) and it's working fine except when i have make **post request using jquery**.

Consider the following request using jquery

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'username': $("#UserName").val() },
            async: false,
            url: "/Wizard/ValidateUserName",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $('#divUser').html("Username is  available");
                    $('#divUser').removeClass("field-validation-error");
                }
                else {
                    $('#divUser').html("Username is not available");
                    $('#divUser').removeClass("field-validation-valid");
                    $('#divUser').addClass("field-validation-error");
                }
                datavalue = data;
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, throwError) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

if i will change **URL: MVCdemo/Wizard/ValidateUserName** then this will work correct way otherwise gives error of **404**.

So how can i handle this type of routing globally in MVC3 application?

Comment: Why don't you want to add `MVCDemo` to the url? It is **part** of the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use MVC razor syntax in jQuery function.

Like below........

```
 function checkUserAvailbility() {
    var datavalue = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'username': $("#UserName").val() },
        async: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("ValidateUserName", "Wizard")',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#divUser').html("Username is  available");
                $('#divUser').removeClass("field-validation-error");
            }
            else {
                $('#divUser').html("Username is not available");
                $('#divUser').removeClass("field-validation-valid");
                $('#divUser').addClass("field-validation-error");
            }
            datavalue = data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, throwError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return datavalue;
}
```

See the diff between url:(property)  of jQuery.

Comment: What happens if the js is in a js file as usual?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is going to the actual url. If you put just /Wizard/ValidateUserName in your browser, it won't work either.

The easy way to solve it is to configure iis to work in the same way yo expect, so you don't need to add the "MVCDemo" prefix for the virtual directory.

Comment: You will need to configure your root site as the application pointing to your mvc application instead of the virtual directory.

Comment: no need to configure, just check my answer will work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
function checkUserAvailbility() {
    var datavalue = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { 'username': $("#UserName").val() },
        async: false,
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Wizard/ValidateUserName")",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $('#divUser').html("Username is  available");
                $('#divUser').removeClass("field-validation-error");
            }
            else {
                $('#divUser').html("Username is not available");
                $('#divUser').removeClass("field-validation-valid");
                $('#divUser').addClass("field-validation-error");
            }
            datavalue = data;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxoptions, throwError) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
    return datavalue;
}
```